# Error accessing bucket using cloud composer

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I'm getting error when trying to access a bucket using cloud composer...

[2019-03-18 11:50:00,651] {models.py:1594} ERROR - 404 GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/gs://xxxx-cloud-composer?projection=noAcl: Not Found

```
    def Ian_Log_Message():
        from google.cloud import storage
        import logging
        logging.info('Hello Ian')
        gcs_bucket=models.Variable.get('gcs_bucket')
        logging.info('gcs_bucket - '+gcs_bucket)
        storage_client = storage.Client()
        bucket_results_out = storage_client.get_bucket(gcs_bucket)
```

The bucket exists and it logs the correct bucket.
I have set a service account against the environment.
The service account has permissions ..

BigQuery Admin

Composer Administrator

Environment and Storage Object Administrator

Composer Worker

Security Reviewer

Service Account Actor

Storage Admin

I also set the service account as an owner against the bucket to see if that helped.

Comment: Just so I understand: Airflow does have some GCS operators. Have you tried using those?

Comment: Apologies but I do not know what you are referring to ?

Comment: You can find here the set of GCP operators. There must be one that can perform the task you need: https://airflow.apache.org/integration.html#gcp-google-cloud-platform

Comment: Thank you, I am now investigating and trying to get the operators to work. I am still having authentication problems but will try and persevere.

Answer (score 0):

404 error indicates that the service couldn't find the given GCS bucket, looking at GCS API [spec](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/get) and your error message, it appears that you probably shouldn't use gs://{bucket}, instead `models.Variable.get('gcs_bucket')` should return just the bucket name (e.g., `foo` as apposed to `gs://foo`).